# Striking out equations

Tags: support, mathjax

I wanted to strike out a part of an answer which I wrote earlier [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160431/sum-of-n-sigman/160440#160440). I tried using `<s> </s>`. This helps in striking out the text but the last two equations are not struck out. For example,

`<s> Striking out text </s>` produces " <s>Striking out text</s> "

However, it fails to strike out in the math mode. For instance,

`<s>Square of sum of two numbers is given by $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$. Here is some text following the math mode.</s>`

produces

<s>Square of sum of two numbers is given by $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$. Here is some text following the math mode.</s>

How to strike out equations and other written stuff in math mode?

This occurs for both chrome (Version 19.0.1084.56) and firefox (Version 13.0 Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0) on Ubuntu 12.04.

This also occurs for both chrome (Version 19.0.1084.56) and Safari (Version 5.1.7 (7534.57.2)) on Mac OSX 10.7.4.

Below is a picture of this question to indicate where it fails to strike the equation.

[image]

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23711/strikethrough-text

Comment: What you did in this question works fine for me (Firefox 3.6.15 on Windows 7). Or did you want the superscripts to be stricken out individually?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Is the equation i.e. $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ struck off as well? If so, can you take a screenshort and post it as an answer? It is interesting that this works fine on windows.

Comment: Chrome 20.0.1132.27 beta on OSX 10.6.8 produces the same result as your screenshot.

Comment: as a work around, since you are striking it out, perhaps you can just remove the dollar signs?

Comment: I've noticed something similar with tags, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4479/). But I don't consider it to be a real problem.

Comment: I will add that the MathJax tutorial on this meta has a separate entry called [Crossing out things](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/13183#13183).

Answer (score 11):

This is not a perfect solution, but it should act reasonably well as a work-around:

```
<s>Square of sum of two numbers is given by
</s>$\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2}$<s>.
Here is some text following the math mode.</s>
```

<s>Square of sum of two numbers is given by</s> $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2}$<s>. Here is some text following the math mode.</s>

The `\require{enclose}` need only be done the first time (but it is not an error to include it multiple times).

Answer (score 6):

At https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8847/53259, Alexander Gruber helpfully offers some alternatives. For some reason, they work for me here at MSE Meta but NOT on MSE. On MSE, I've discovered that the following work, where I just use "\require{cancel}" instead of \require{...cancel}

$\require{cancel} \cancel{2-2}$ \require{cancel} \cancel{2-2}

$\require{cancel} \bcancel{2-2}$ \require{cancel} \bcancel{2-2}

$\require{cancel} \xcancel{2-2}$ \require{cancel} \xcancel{2-2}

$\require{cancel} \cancelto{0}{2-2}$ \require{cancel} \cancelto{0}{2-2}

Answer (score 3):

It seems to work exactly as it should for me. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Image of the above question with stricken equation]

Firefox 3.6.15 on Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks. I never thought it would be an issue with the OS/browser. I have added my screenshot in the question.

Comment: On the other hand, Chrome 19.0.1084.56 m (also Windows 7) does fail to strike the equation, with results comparable to the Ubunto screenshot in the question.

Comment: @Marvis: Rendering problems on the web are "almost always" (or at least more often than not) browser-specific. Sometimes also OS specific, primarily when the availability of system fonts plays a role.

Comment: And Firefox 13.0.1 on Windows also fails to strike out the equation.

Comment: This has never worked for me. I have gone through several upgrades of Firefox (currently at ver 12.0), and given up hope. Running on Win XP.

Comment: Firefox versions (roughly) 10 through 13 (on various OS) all fail to strike out the equation. I think it has more to do with the browser than with the OS.