# How to cross out mathematical expressions?

Tags: support, mathjax

How can I cross out a mathematical expression **with a horizontal line?** Thanks.

Comment: See also: [Striking out equations](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4473/49437)

Comment: I am slightly confused as to why this was closed as "off topic", and I am listed as one of the closers. I voted to close it because it is a duplicate! (And if this is off topic then so is the original, so I think we are having double-standards...)

Comment: @hardmath I have already voted to close it, so cannot vote again. (But I agree, as that was what my original vote was trying to do!)

Comment: @user1729:  I have cast the first stone... er, vote to close as duplicate!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In text environment you can use `<strike> </strike>`, for example: <strike>strike</strike>.

In math environment, you can cross out expressions using `cancel` `bcancel` `xcancel` or `cancelto` as long as you `require` them first.

$\require{cancel} \cancel{2-2}$ `$\require{cancel} \cancel{2-2}$`

$\require{bcancel} \bcancel{2-2}$ `$\require{bcancel} \bcancel{2-2}$`

$\require{xcancel} \xcancel{2-2}$ `$\require{xcancel} \xcancel{2-2}$`

$\require{cancelto} \cancelto{0}{2-2}$ `$\require{cancelto} \cancelto{0}{2-2}$`

As far as I know there is no perfect execution of horizontal strike-through in math environment.  You can try to do it using css, with `\style{text-decoration:line-through}{...}`.  This works fine sometimes
$$\style{text-decoration:line-through}{abcd\sum\prod\bigotimes}$$
but it messes up with subscripts and superscripts and fractions
$$\style{text-decoration:line-through}{\sum_{i=0}^n\left(x_iy^i\frac{z}{u}\right)}$$
I hope someone knows of a more reliable way to do horizontal strike-through in math environment, but I think this may be it.

Comment: In a similar question [Davide Cervone suggests](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4478/49437) using `$\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2}$` which produces horizontal strike-throughs.

Comment: Great!  Thanks @Martin.

Comment: See the [MathJax doc on enclose.](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#enclose) (= MathML [<menclose>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MathML/Element/menclose))

Comment: Thanks for sharing us the codes Alexander. :)

Comment: or raising or lowering overline or underline.