# How do I display stricken text on math.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, mathjax

As you know, the [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) branch of stack exchange uses the $\mathcal{MathJax}$ web plug-in.

How do I strike-out text on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

[image: SCREEN CAPTURE OF SOME STRICKEN TEXT]

[image: SCREEN CAPTURE OF AN EXAMPLE OF STRICKEN OUT TEXT]

I read the documentation for a $\mathcal{MathJax}$ command named [`\cancel`](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/cancel.html). However, when I try to use [`\cancel`](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/cancel.html) I get some error messages.

```
$\cancel{\text{ is always between } x \text{ and } y }$

$\xcancel{math}$

$\cancelto{value}{math}$
```

[image: ERROR MESSAGES SCREEN CAP]

Comment: See [Crossing things out](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/13183#13183) in the MathJax Tutorial.

Comment: HTML `<s>stricken</s>` works in normal markdown (but apparently not in comments).

Comment: One cannot close a question as a duplicate of an answer, but as @PeterPhipps points out, this has already been answered.

Comment: Some related posts: [How to cross out mathematical expressions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8840), [How to write a line through text?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29977) and [Striking out equations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4473).

Comment: There is a `\require{cancel}`, but no `\cancel`