# How to write a line through text?

Tags: support, mathjax, markdown, formatting

How to write a line through text or words ?

Like the \underline{} in latex but in the middle the line, to indicate something is wrong.

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13183/18398

Comment: In the question I linked to, it might take a while for the MathJax to render, so you'll need to be patient.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche In my opinion, this is not a duplicate, since the OP is asking about striking out *text* and not mathematical formulas. ([This message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49565695#49565695) in chat can also be considered as a confirmation that they are asking about text: "And yes I wanted to put a line through a word, not an equation.".) Of course, it is possible the the duplicate for such question is somewhere on this meta, too - I did not find it in the short time I've spent searching.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, okay, I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For *text* you do can simply use the corresponding html tag and write `<s>strikethrough text</s>` to get: <s>strikethrough text</s>. I will explicitly mention that this works in *posts* but *not in comments*. See also: [Does Markdown have a way to express strikeout?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63768) and [How to strike text?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180256)

I will also add that in chat you can use the syntax `---strikethrough text---`. (Although in this question you are probably interested more in posts on main than in chat.)

If you want something similar in equations, you might have a look at the older posts on this meta, such as [Striking out equations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4473) and the entry on [Crossing out things](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/13183#13183) in the MathJax tutorial on this meta site.

Comment: This comment is just to illustrate that the same syntax does not work in comments: <s>strikethrough text</s>.

Comment: Thank you for your answer